# How to know which website is causing the sql server to stop responding?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have multiple databases on the same sql server 2008. Some times the server stops working and I should restart it to make it work again. Is there an easy way to know which application or website caused this stop?
Or can I know which database takes the most of the server power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Computer was restarted (one of causes).
Use Sql Server Configuration Manager to set Start Mode to *Automatic*

[image]

2) Use *Event viewer* (Windows Logs/System) to get more information about stops/starts of service:

[image]